# Rewrite rule in joomla .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have added this line in joomla .htaccess to remove part of the url.

Original URL Example - http://odishayellowpages.in/item/scientific-suppliers

Required URL Example - http://odishayellowpages.in/scientific-suppliers

I have used this rewrite rule - but it doens't make any difference.

```
# Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
## End - Custom redirects
```

Comment: I have tried that with no luck.

Comment: Ok when I am  adding `RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]` just below rewrite engine I am getting the url like this - `http://odishayellowpages.in/var/www/odishayellowpages.in/web/scientific-suppliers

Comment: no `/item/` is not a real directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

You need to use `/` at start of target URL to avoid it getting appended to current filesystem path.

Comment: I am getting the result like this - http://odishayellowpages.in/var/www/odishayellowpages.in/web/scientific-suppliers

Comment: That is your old browser cache, clear the cache and retest.

Comment: You are right, but now I am getting 404 not found error. Any suggestion.

Comment: This rule will redirect to `http://odishayellowpages.in/scientific-suppliers`. 404 is not the problem with this rule. Your existing handlers should be able to resolve that URL.

Comment: Ok Thanks so much. I will look into it.